# why only one node can sync blocks in my private eth chain?

Tags: ethereum

I have setup 4 nodes (named A, B, C, D) in a PC (windows 8.1) to build my private chain using geth v1.8.11.

A node is the first one to be created and have 1 account.

B node is the second one to be created and have 1 account.

A and B connected using `admin.addPeer`.

A and B mined 336 blocks. Their blocks are synced.

[image]

C node and D node were setup later.

C and D connected A using admin.addPeer. But C and D displayed the following info and the blocks can't be sync.

[image]

And eth.syncing shows:

[image]

eth.blockNumber shows: 0

B, C, D nodes start with the following command:

```
geth --datadir "H:\blockchain\eth\dataX" --networkid 15 --nodiscover --port="3030X" --ipcdisable --rpc --rpcapi "admin,debug,eth,miner,net,personal,shh,txpool,web3" --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpcport "31X00" --rpccorsdomain "*" --ws --wsport="31X01" --wsaddr="0.0.0.0" --wsorigins "*" console
```

So why C and D sync fail?

the block number is 0 but the startingBlock is 271, is it normal?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may arise if the new node is not initiated using the same genesis file with which the base node is created.
Make sure of it.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion. After I clean the datadir folders and re-setup these nodes, they works well now. But I still confuse "the block number is 0 but the startingBlock is 271" this issue,